# WCF : namespace of datamember different than parent

Tags: wcf, namespaces, datamember, datacontracts

We have to implement a provided external API.
This API cannot be changed.
For this API, SOAP messages are exchanged, and one of them dealing with fault exception is like that  :

```
<h:Parent xmlns:h="namespace1">
    <Member xmlns="namespace2">0</Member>
</h:Parent>
```

While we can implement this with other frameworks such as asmx, we do not succeed in doing it in WCF : data member seems to have the same namespace as the datacontract.
Is there a way to add a namespace for datamember ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can change the namespace associated to the Member data contract using the [Namespace property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.namespace.aspx).

Comment: Do you have a sample of code for that ? 
Because I think this will change the namespace for the datacontract and for the member, and not just for the member.

Comment: I mean add the namespace attribue to the contract of the Member class, not the Parent

Comment: i have understood what you meant, but data member has not this "namespace" attribute. 
If it works on your WCF, could you please show me the code ? I may have missed something as we are totally new on WCF.

Comment: The DataMember attribute does not have this property but DataContract does. Add it to the DataContract attribute of the Member data contract, not to the property of type Member.

Comment: Hi.
We have tried, but then our SOAP message is like that :
`    <h:Parent xmlns:h="namespace1">
        <h:subNode xmlns:h="namespace2">
            <Member>0</Member>
        </h:subNode>
    </h:Parent>`
which is not wanted (subNode is not wanted)